# The actual GUI window size is different from the QT Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am making GUI using Qt designer.
The Qt designer can intuitively show the location and size of the GUI, so I chose it.
However, when operating the code, the size of the GUI and qt designer is different. This also ruined the sizes of other widgets. I don't know for some reason.

Below is my simple code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class MyWindow(QWidget) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.dlg = loadUi('a.ui')
        self.dlg.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myWin = MyWindow()
app.exec()
```

QT Designer
[image]

GUI
[image]

I searched several sites, but the cause was unknown. I thought it was a setup related issue, but I don't know the exact cause.

Comment: There's some essential information missing. Have you defined the window size in QT designer? You can set a fixed size in the main window properties or when you create your main window in code.

Comment: You're using layout managers in the wrong way. The layout you've been dragging from the widget box must be put within a main layout manager in the container widget(s). Right click on an empty area of the groupbox and select an appropriate layout from the related menu, then add/drag the inner layouts within that layout. See the documentation about [using layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Also, always check the object inspector icons: if you see that small red "forbidden" icon near a container widget, it means that you didn't set a layout for it.